# Fastest way to SELECT a row from a table in a database (Microsoft SQL server)

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, select

I have a huge table with one int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY column.

I guess making the SELECT query using that primary key is the fastest way for the database to find the row in the table isn't it?

If that is true i still have a question.
Is that query as fast as a call to a dictionary by key or the database still has to read all the rows from the beginning (the Primary Key column) till it finds the row itself?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: An index in SQL Server builds an index tree - searching through that index tree is **very fast** and is **DEFINITELY** not a "look at all records" kind of approach. On the contrary - even for **millions** of rows, SQL Server's query engine will only compare probably 5 or 6 items of data to your `ID` value specified to actually find the row you're looking for

Comment: Is that index created automatically or do i have to do anything to the table declaration?

Comment: djdev indirectly answered this one. So the index table is created whenever a primary key is created. Ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using primary key is obviously the fastest way to access a particular row.

If you want to understand how it works, you have to understand how index works.

**In general it works like that :**

Let's say you have a table `t1(col1,col2...col10)` and you have an index on `col1`.
Index on `col1` means that you have some data structure which contains pairs `(col1, rec_id)`
and `rec_id` allows direct access to row with appropriate `col1`.
The data structure is ordered by `col1` and therefore allows efficient searching by `col1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think searching in dictionary works per dictionary search algorithm which should be more like binary search kind.

When you declare a column as Primary key in table, then that column is indexed, hence it should be working based on hashing principle, so searching is definitely NOT row by row as you mentioned.

Finally, yes it is the common and fast way, but you should be selective about the number of columns and rows you need in your sql query. Avoid fetching large number of rows per select call.

Comment: I only need one and only one per call. My question was to avoid the creation of a dictionary class (which i think ill create anyways in the end) that would store the rows that have been selected lately by users and that removes them from the dictionary when users stop using them after a time. The use of those rows will be instense for short periods so even if the database calls are fast, a native dictionary class would be a much better aproach for this situation always controlling that there is enough memory in the server to store the dictionary. IMO.